# Prevent page screen scrolling up when keyboard is opened (C#-XAML-Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, keyboard-events

​Generally when `TextBox` is focused, soft-keyboard will be open, but the problem is that by default the page shift upwards when the keyboard is opened and again shift previous position when user closes the keyboard by tapping on the screen.

I need the page to shift to a certain Y. And I need to be able to close the keyboard when I click a "Done" Button not only when I tap on the screen.

I am trying to find the Default `ScrollViewer` of the Page that is scrolling:
Two events on the TextBox:

```
private void PNotesTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parentScrollViewer = FindParent<ScrollViewer>(this);
    parentScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    parentScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, offset, null, true);
    parentScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
}

private void PNotesTextBox_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        offset = e.GetPosition(PNotesTextBox).Y - 10;
}
```

In the MainPage Constructor:

```
    var inputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
    inputPane.Showing += OnShowingInputPane;


    private async void OnShowingInputPane(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
       {
           await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
           {
              var parentScrollViewer = FindParent<ScrollViewer>(this);
              parentScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
              offset = 580 - args.OccludedRect.Top;
              parentScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, offset, null, true);
              parentScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
            });
       }

public static T FindParent<T>(FrameworkElement reference)
   where T : FrameworkElement
   {
       FrameworkElement parent = reference;
       while (parent != null)
       {
           parent = parent.Parent as FrameworkElement;

           var rc = parent as T;
           if (rc != null)
           {
              return rc;
           }
       }
       return null;
    }
```

When I deploy my application on the simulator with `10.6" 1024x768 (4:3 100%)` and `10.6" 1366x768 (16:9 100%)` it works perfectly and the keyboard is shown in a way the ScrollViewer is scrolled with the TextBox in the right position, only for these two resolutions.

The problem is that I should make it work the same way on all the Screens resolutions. Any help how can I make my code dynamic for all screens sizes?

Comment: This shows a lack of effort. Have you tried anything? Got some code? Please read up on [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then add the missing bits and pieces to your question.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding the code I tried implementing. Thank you for the guidelines!

Comment: Where do you want the textbox to end up? The problem is likely in the magic number 580. You will probably need to calculate that number based on current scale/resolution or some other relative number.

Comment: Also, is this a window 10 universal app, windows 8.1 app or a windows phone app?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868246.aspx)

`When the touch keyboard appears, it automatically repositions your UI to ensure that the focused element remains visible. This can cause other important areas of your UI to move off screen. However, you can disable the default behavior and make your own UI adjustments when the touch keyboard appears`

`Key presses on the touch keyboard raise KeyDown and KeyUp events just like key presses on hardware keyboards. However, the touch keyboard will not raise input events for Ctrl+A, Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+C, and Ctrl+V, which are reserved for text manipulation in the input control`

There is a pretty decent example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/keyboard-events-sample-866ba41c)

Comment: The example is a little complex using and scrolling a new ScrollViewer (with an animation), or all I need is to execute the ChangedView method of the default ScrollViewer of the MainPage, on all screen sizes.